# bash: wget stdout to grep "word" if not exist grep "word2" print word|word2

Tags: bash, shell, grep, wget

I recently came across a new website called pwnedlist.com, it keeps track of compromised e-mail accounts.

I figured it would be a good practice exercise for me to try and query each email from a list.

I have all that done, fine and dandy, but my issue is that I don't know a good method for
have the stdout pass through both grep's without wget'ing a second time for the second string. Here's what I have so far....

```
    #!/usr/local/bin/bash

    if [ -z "$1" ]
    then
            echo "Usage: $0 <list>"
    exit
    fi

    for address in $(cat $1)
    do

    echo -n "$address       "
    wget -O - --post-data "query_input=$address" pwnedlist.com/query 2>/dev/null |
    grep -i congrats | cut -d '>' -f 2 | cut -d '<' -f 1

    done
    echo
```

This works like I want it to:

```
    $ ./querypwnlist testfile
    jonschipp@gmail.com     Congrats! Your email is not in our list.
    somebody@somebody.com   Congrats! Your email is not in our list.
    crap@crap.com           Congrats! Your email is not in our list.
```

My issue is that I need to find a way to grep for the other parameter, the not-so-good one

```
   grep -i "we found"
```

is the string I need.

Here's the HTML:

```
   <div id="query_result_negative" class='query_result_footer'>... we found your email/username in our database. It was last seen on 2011-08-30. Please read on.</div>
```

I tried this in hopes that it would print those "compromised" emails as well but it didn't work, my logic is incorrect.

```
   wget ..... | ( grep -i congrats || grep -i "we found" ) | cut ....
```

Also, my choice of cut options looks kinda bulky/superfluous, any ideas for something cleaner? Using one command instead of sending it through cut a second time?

Here's the HTML:

```
    <div id="query_result_negative" class='query_result_footer'>Congrats! Your email is not in our list.</div>
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use a grep that will check for both strings?

```
... grep -i "congratz\|we found" ...
```